# morphTargets shrinks the whole mesh not only related vertices

Tags: three.js

I'm using a gltf import in three.js ; the object is an armature with a group of at least 2 meshes.  For some reasons I need to  MERGE geometries into a SINGLE mesh ; consequently I merged the geometries and put materials into an array of materials and all index tables and skin indexes updated in accordance. Everything is OK : object shows perfectly up and bones animation works well ; BUT the morphanimation poses problem : the morph influences act correctly on related vertices but shrinks also the whole mesh ( - even more if the morphatrgets positions are all set to 0 - just for testing). If I DO NOT MERGE the meshes but keep rather the children relationship morph targets work perfectly (as in the GLTF viewer) but this prevents me form using other personal functions I need. So, the question is : does the merging of meshes pose problem for the morph target animations ? I tried 2 ways for merge : convert initial buffergeometries to geometries, merge them and go back to buffergeometry. This gives the result above. I also observed the size of attributes.position increases by 10. So I tested the .merge directly on buffer geometries but the resulting buffergeometry has empty attributes.position ? And nothing works. Could any one tell me how buffergeometries including morphtargets can be merged ? Thanks for any help ...

Comment: I managed  to merge the geometries of my group with BufferGeometryUtils and to add groups for multiple materials. So this works now but the morphtargets influence still has a scale down effect. The morph target is applied correctly but the whole geometry shrinks down. Don't know wht ?

Answer (score 1):

I got finally the solution to my problem "merge buffer geometries with multiple materials and morphtargets" : 
1) merge the geometries of my group with BufferGeometryUtils into a single buffergeometry
2) map materials by adding groups to the merged geometry for the multiple materials according to each buffer (from the array of buffer which have been merged) index length
3) finally set mesh.geometry.morphTargetsRelative to true (this was the reason for the unwanted scaling effect on the whole object)
Hope this can help others